# conditionally modify object's property ES6

Tags: ecmascript-6

I have below object in ES6.

```
    const myObject = {
    list1: [
    { title:'test1', acted:false, currentAction:false
    },
    { title:'test2', acted:false, currentAction:false
    },
    { title:'test3', acted:false, currentAction:false
    },
    { title:'test3', acted:false, currentAction:false
    }],
   list2:
     [
    { title:'data1', acted:false, currentAction:false
    },
    { title:'data2', acted:false, currentAction:false
    },
    { title:'data3', acted:false, currentAction:false
    },
    { title:'data4', acted:false, currentAction:true,
    }],
      list3:
     [
    { title:'a1', acted:false, currentAction:false
    },
    { title:'a2', acted:false, currentAction:false
    },
    { title:'a3', acted:false, currentAction:false
    },
    { title:'a4', acted:false, currentAction:false,
    }],

}
```

I would like to check if any `currentAction` property within any list is true make it false and return the whole modified object.

I know how to directly modify object property but not sure about any list within object can be filter and modified.

this is what I tried

```
const newObject = { ...myObject, currentAction:true }
```

Comment: Do you want to mutate the object in place or create a copy of the object with the new data?

Comment: I assumed the answer is “mutate the object in place” for my answer. I’ll update my answer if that turns out to be wrong.

Comment: You have a stray comma at the end of your code block.

Comment: @FelixKling, I would liket create a new copy of object first, modified it if it currentAction found to be true in any property.

Comment: To clarify further, do you want to create a new copy of the object in all cases, or only when some `currentAction` is `true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried this code:

```
const newObject = { ...myObject, currentAction:true }
```

This won’t filter anything, and it doesn’t come close to what you want. But it does help clarify the question: when you say “return the whole modified object”, apparently you really mean the whole thing:

```
{
    list1: [
    { title:'test1', acted:false, currentAction:false
    },
    { title:'test2', acted:false, currentAction:false
    },
    { title:'test3', acted:false, currentAction:false
    },
    { title:'test3', acted:false, currentAction:false
    }],
   list2:
     [
    { title:'data1', acted:false, currentAction:false
    },
    { title:'data2', acted:false, currentAction:false
    },
    { title:'data3', acted:false, currentAction:false
    },
    { title:'data4', acted:false, currentAction:true,
    }],
      list3:
     [
    { title:'a1', acted:false, currentAction:false
    },
    { title:'a2', acted:false, currentAction:false
    },
    { title:'a3', acted:false, currentAction:false
    },
    { title:'a4', acted:false, currentAction:false,
    }],

}
```

Now let’s answer the question. First, to reset the `currentAction` properties to `false`:

```
for (listIndex = 0; listIndex < 3; ++listIndex) {
    for (const innerObject of myObject["list" + listIndex]) {
        innerObject.currentAction = false;
    }
}
```

The notation `"list" + listIndex` is string concatenation. The notation `myObject[...]` is used to access a property using a computed property name. This gives us an array, which we iterate over using `for (const innerObject of ...)`.

Now, to return the new object: no need, because it’s already in `myObject`. Even though `myObject` was declared as a `const`, that just means that the object *reference* it contains is constant. In other words, `myObject` always refers to the same object. But the object itself can change.

---

**Edit:** Felix Kling suggested using `for (const list of Object.values(myObject))` to iterate over `myObject`’s properties. This way we don’t make any assumptions about the number of properties or their names. I also renamed `innerObject` to `listItem`.

```
for (const list of Object.values(myObject)) {
    for (const listItem of list) {
        listItem.currentAction = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use `for (const list of Object.values(myObject))` to iterate over the property values. Then there is no need to make assumptions about the property names.

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for your comment, but object inside object here list1 is list2 is just illustration purpose, names are different

Comment: @FelixKling, I would like to copy existing object modified (if any currentAction is found to be true) and return it